# Django Model fields - Imagefield and filefield

Tags: django, django-models

Does django saves files and images directly into database or in some local storage, and saves only path in database?

(In imagefield and filefield)

Answer (score 0):

Without any configuration in your settings django will in both cases, for `ImageField` and `FileField`, save files into the base directory of the django project itself.

Django does not save file data directly into the database. A string representation of the relative path to the file/image will be stored in the model object's `FileField`/`ImageField` column instead.

If you have a Model with a `FileField` like so

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files/upload')
```

and you have configured your `settings.py` to include

```py
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

An uploaded file such as `example.txt` would be uploaded to

`/media/files/upload/example.txt`

and the value stored in the `file` column of the database table would be

`/files/upload/example.txt`